# Как с помощью регулярных выражений разделить строку на слова?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, строки

У меня есть подобные строки `OneWord`. Мне нужно разделить их на `One` и `Word` соответственно. Как это сделать с помощью регулярных выражений? Я написал такое

```
let str = "OneWord";

let parts = str.split(new RegExp("[A-Z]"))
```

Но оно выдает мне строки без больших букв. Помогите составить правильное регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```js
let str = "OneWord";
console.log( str.split(/(?!^)(?=[A-Z])/) )
console.log( str.match(/[A-Z][^A-Z]*/g) )
```

В первом случае используется метод `String#split` с регулярным выражением `(?!^)(?=[A-Z])`, которое находит позиции в строке перед заглавной буквой (`(?=[A-Z])`) (но не в начале строки (`(?!^)`)).

Во втором случае используется метод `String#match` с регулярным выражением `[^A-Z]*`, которое находит заглавную букву (`[A-Z]`) и все ноль и более последующие символы за ней, отличные от заглавной буквы (`[^A-Z]*`)).

Если нужна поддержка любых букв:

```js
let str = "ОдноСлово";
console.log( str.split(/(?!^)(?=\p{Lu})/u) )
console.log( str.match(/\p{Lu}\P{Lu}*/gu) )
```